# Get real iphone resolution - jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, resolution

i am programming a jQuery Plugin, which requires the exactly screen resolution.

It's well known that the iphone response 320*480 (iphone 4), but i need the correct size (retina size).

Of course the problem exists also with the retina ipad.

What should i do in that case?

Thanks for your responses.

**/edit**

ok, i have done it, but i think there is a mistake

my script:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width() * window.devicePixelRatio;
var screenHeight = $(window).height() * window.devicePixelRatio;

i get the following values:
portrait:
screenWidth = 640
screenHeight = 960

landscape:
screenWidth = 960
screenHeight = 960
```

with the following meta tag:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webkit browsers you can get the device pixel ratio using `window.devicePixelRatio`.  Multiply that by the resolution and you should have the number you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i updatet my question, still have a problem

Comment: Is there content on your page so that `$(window).height()` is actually reporting the browser's full height and not just the screen?  Try `screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio` and see if that gets you better results.

Comment: screen.height didnt work, but i made some mistake
your previous solution works perfect
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply it by 2 and you will get the real resolution. http://smartphones.techcrunch.com/q/152/4793/What-are-the-specifications-of-the-Apple-iPhone-4S-smartphone

Comment: The OP also mentions the iPad.  The new iPad mini has a device pixel ratio of 1.5, so multiplying by 2 would give incorrect values.

Comment: since when iPad mini is with retina display?

Comment: never lost a word about ipad mini @Vytautas Butkus